# I can't callback in a python generator

Tags: python-3.x, callback

I can't callback in method `__new__`, the code bypass the line `return callback('hello')`. Why?

```py
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, callback):
        return callback('hello')


class B:
    def start1(self):
        yield A(self.start2) 

    def start2(self, r):
        yield r


generator = B().start1()
for g in generator:
    print(g)
```

How can I make it work?

even replacing `return callback('hello')`with `yield from callback('hello')` It don't works. (I'm using python 3.7.4)

Comment: *"I can't callback"* is not very descriptive - what is the expected result and what is the actual result? Is there an error, a wrong output, an infinite loop?

Comment: did you mean to `print(g.start3())`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes that's good, but I edit the post because I was wrong to write the right function. Do you know how to solve now?

Comment: @kaya3 I edit the post. Try now the code please